# Can I put an AJAX request within another AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display data from to different tables in the databases in one modal. Since it's impossible to send two url's in one AJAX request, I decided to send another AJAX request within an AJAX request. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"getEvent.php",
        method: "GET",
        data:{
            cid:event_id
        },
        dataType: "json",

        success:function(retval){
            $("#event_img").html("");
            $("#event_title").html("");
            $("#event_description").html("");
            $("#event_start").html("");
            $("#event_material_req").html("");
            $("#event_occupation").html("");

            $.ajax({
                url: "getOccupation.php",
                method: "GET",
                data:{
                    cid:event_id
                },
                dataType: "json"
                success: function(retval){
                    for(i=0; i<retval.length; i++){
                        event_occupation = retval[i].noVolunteers;
                        event_occupation += retval[i].occupationName;
                    }

                    $("#event_occupation").append(event_occupation);

                }
            });



            event_img = "../admin/eventImages/"+retval[0].event_img;
            event_id = retval[0].event_id;
            event_name = retval[0].event_name;
            event_description = retval[0].event_description;
            event_location = retval[0].event_location;
            event_start = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a', retval[0].event_start);
            event_material_req = retval[0].event_material_req;


            $("#event_img").attr("src", event_img);
            $("#event_title").append(event_name);
            $("#event_description").append(event_description);
            $("#event_start").append(event_start);
            $("#event_material_req").append(event_material_req);
            $("#readmore").modal("show");

            publishToPast(event_id);
        }

    });
```

I know I did not do it right since the only I can retrieve is from the the `getEvent.php`

Comment: Yep... This is completely fine... Few things to check. Any errors in Console? And what does the response say? What's your Network tab looking like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in you code. but I can't understand it either :)

you have the `event_id` before those two ajax calls. so why do you need to put your second ajax in the first one ?

as I think you might need the result from the first call in the second call. ( BUT you didn't use any of the result for the second call) so lets just think that you want to show some data synchronously. first get the first call and show it and then get the second call and show other things.

Ok. the point here is you get the callback value as `retval` in both calls.

then you put all your UI code outside the second call. I mean this part

```
 event_img = "../admin/eventImages/"+retval[0].event_img;
            event_id = retval[0].event_id;
            event_name = retval[0].event_name;
            event_description = retval[0].event_description;
            event_location = retval[0].event_location;
            event_start = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a', retval[0].event_start);
            event_material_req = retval[0].event_material_req;


            $("#event_img").attr("src", event_img);
            $("#event_title").append(event_name);
            $("#event_description").append(event_description);
            $("#event_start").append(event_start);
            $("#event_material_req").append(event_material_req);
            $("#readmore").modal("show");

            publishToPast(event_id);
```

so it doesn't respect your success callback in the second call and show it before it ends and only when call 1 has successfully called.

another thing is you have a syntax error in second call.

```
url: "getOccupation.php",
                method: "GET",
                data:{
                    cid:event_id
                },
                dataType: "json"
                success: function(retval){
```

you forget a `,` after the "json". it should be like this

```
 url: "getOccupation.php",
                    method: "GET",
                    data:{
                        cid:event_id
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(retval){
```

Comment: Are you sure about what you have said? No errors? Seriously?

Comment: Since you said it here: `you forget a ;` - It should be `,`. I did read your full answer mate. `:)`

Comment: So your answer was wrong before and you didn't check, while I checked fully, and this what happens. Right?